# datastax java driver update fails silently

Tags: java, updates, datastax

I have a shared (with other applications) Cassandra database that is clustered in 2 different nodes. I'm using Cassandra Database 2.1.2 and Java Datastax driver version 2.1.4.

I Have created a Do similar to this:

```
package com.me.name.data.model.cassandra;

@Table(name = "name")
public final class NameDo
{
/*
 * the unique identifier
 */
@PartitionKey
private UUID            id;

/*
 * The package name
 */
@Column(name = "name")
private String          name;

/*
 * the version number
 */
@Column(name = "version")
private String          version;

/*
 * the trial period configured.
 */
@Column(name = "period")
private Integer         period;

/*
 * The last update date
 */
@Column(name = "status_last_update")
private Date            statusLastUpdate;

/*
 * The trial start date
 */
@Column(name = "trial_start_date")
private Date            trialStartDate;

/*
 * The description
 */
@Column(name = "description")
private String           description;
```

And I'm using a Cluster like this:

```
public final class ClusterManagerServiceImpl implements ClusterManagerService
{
private @Value("${cassandra.contactpoints}") String clusterHost;
private Cluster                                     cluster;
private static final Logger                         LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ClusterManagerServiceImpl.class);

@Autowired
private AuthProviderImpl authProvider;

public String getClusterHost()
{
    return clusterHost;
}

public void setClusterHost(String clusterHost)
{
    this.clusterHost = clusterHost;
}

public Cluster getCluster()
{
    if (cluster == null)
    {
        try
        {
            this.createCluster();
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e)
        {
            LOGGER.error(e);
        }
    }
    return cluster;
}

public void setCluster(Cluster cluster)
{
    this.cluster = cluster;
}

public void createCluster() throws UnknownHostException
{
    try
    {
        if (cluster == null)
        {
            LOGGER.debug("opening new Cluster");
            setCluster(Cluster.builder().withAuthProvider(authProvider).addContactPoints(InetAddress.getByName(getClusterHost())).build());
        }
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e)
    {
        LOGGER.error(e);
    }
}
```

So every time I want to do an update or an insert I do this:

```
protected Session createSessionOnCluster(Session session) {
    LOGGER.debug("opening new session");
    session = clusterManagerServiceImpl.getCluster().connect(KEYSPACE_NAME);

    return (session);
}

private Mapper<NameDo> createPackageMapper(Session session) {
    MappingManager manager = new MappingManager(session);
    Mapper<NameDo> mapper = manager.mapper(NameDo.class);
    return mapper;
}

public NameDo updateName(NameDo nameDo)
        {
    Session session = null;

    nameDo.setStatusLastUpdate(new Date());
    session = createSessionOnCluster(session);

    Mapper<NameDo> mapper = createPackageMapper(session);
    mapper.save(nameDo);

    return nameDo;
}
```

So... after all this... I'm doing the update and it throws no error at all but then after I check the database there's been no update made to my Name table...

1. Does anyone know what could be causing this?
2. Is it Cassandra?
3. is it the DataStax driver?
4. Is there a workaround?